# Spotfire: How to make all values for a given ID Null if one of the child values is null

Tags: spotfire

I have Spotfire and I need to set all values for a calculated field null if one value is null for an ID Set

```
ID                 Date           Calculated Max Date or Null
I201807017         8/12/2018       NULL
I201807017         8/11/2018       NULL
I201807017                         NULL
I20190808          8/12/2018       8/12/2018
I20190808          7/30/2018       8/12/2018
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to count the number of records in a group and check to see if it equals the count of non null values. I did:

```
case  when Count([ID]) over ([ID])!=Sum(case  when [Date] is null then 0 else 1 end) over ([ID]) then null else Max([Date]) over ([ID]) end
```

Comment: great and creative solution, @blakeoft!